# BigQuery table join based on condition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have two tables - Vehicle Information and Updates. The Vehicle Information table has columns such as VehicleNum, model, and model_year, while the Updates table has columns such as vehicleNum, Version, and time.
I need to check for certain conditions. For example, if the model is  xxx  and the model year is My21, I need to check if the vehicle had the update 3.2.1. If it had the update, I need to return the time of the update with value 1.0 as app version. Similarly, if the model is xyz and the model year is My22, I need to check if the vehicle had the update 5.6.0. If it had the update, I need to return the time of the update with value 1.3 as app version. These conditions need to be applied for multiple vehicle lines and model years.

Please suggest an approach with code!

We tried out a  couple of approaches but nothing worked out. PS: ChatGPT's code failed as well!

Answer (score 2):

You have difference between join and projection.

You have to join the tables and then to filter the projection, try something like this

```
select
VehicleNum, model, model_year,
CASE time
WHEN model = "xxx" AND model_year = "My21" AND Version = "3.2.1" THEN time
WHEN model = "xyx" AND model_year = "My22" AND Version = "5.6.0" THEN time
ELSE NULL
END,
CASE Version
WHEN model = "xxx" AND model_year = "My21" AND Version = "3.2.1" THEN "1.0"
WHEN model = "xyx" AND model_year = "My22" AND Version = "5.6.0" THEN "1.3"
ELSE NULL
END
from vehicule c join updates u on c.vehiculeNum = u.vehiculeNum
```

---

**Edit 1**

With your comment, I can propose this query

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
VehicleNum, model, model_year,
CASE time
WHEN model = "xxx" AND model_year = "My21" AND Version = "3.2.1" THEN time
WHEN model = "xyx" AND model_year = "My22" AND Version = "5.6.0" THEN time
ELSE NULL
END,
CASE Version
WHEN model = "xxx" AND model_year = "My21" AND Version = "3.2.1" THEN "1.0"
WHEN model = "xyx" AND model_year = "My22" AND Version = "5.6.0" THEN "1.3"
ELSE NULL
END
FROM vehicule c JOIN updates u ON c.vehiculeNum = u.vehiculeNum
)
SELECT VehicleNum, model, model_year, ARRAY_AGG(struct(time, version)) AS val 
FROM data
WHERE time IS NOT NULL and version IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @guillaume. With the aprroach mentioned, the join creates multiple rows for one model since it has several versions in the Updates table. I would want only a single row for each vehicle.

And, if a vehicle meets multiple criteria, such as version 1.3 and 1.0, I would like them to be an array structure with timestamps.

Comment: You can update the projection with a WITH keyword for instance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply

There is a problem with this approach. The join creates multiple rows for one model since it has several versions in the Updates table. I need only a single row for each vehicle.

And, if a vehicle meets multiple criteria, such as version 1.3 and 1.0, I would like them to be an array structure with timestamps.
Thank you again!